# Minimal polynomial for $\zeta+\zeta^5$ for a primitive seventh root of unity $\zeta$

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, galois-theory, cyclotomic-polynomials

Minimal polynomial for $\zeta+\zeta^5$ for a primitive seventh root of unity $\zeta$

I have asked a similar problem [Minimal Polynomial of $\zeta+\zeta^{-1}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/460930/minimal-polynomial-of-zeta-zeta-1) and i tried to repeat similar idea

Consider $\alpha=\zeta+\zeta^5$ and consider $\sigma \in Gal(\mathbb{Q}(\zeta)/\mathbb{Q})$ defined as $\sigma(\zeta)=\zeta^2$

so, we consider conjugates of $\alpha$ under $\sigma$

- $\alpha=\zeta+\zeta^5$
- $\sigma(\alpha)=\sigma(\zeta+\zeta^5)=\zeta^2+\zeta^3$
- $\sigma^2(\alpha)=\sigma(\zeta^2+\zeta^3)=\zeta^4+\zeta^6$
- $\sigma^3(\alpha)=\alpha$

So i would consider $(x-\alpha)(x-\sigma(\alpha))(x-\sigma^2(\alpha))$

This is giving me $x^3+x^2+(2+\zeta+\zeta^2+\zeta^4)x-1$

I do not know how to make coefficient of $x$ as real..

Please help me to fill this gap..

Comment: You only have half the Galois group. The Galois group has 6 elements, but your $\sigma$ has order 3.

Comment: @GerryMyerson : Oh.. I was thinking i can take any $\sigma$ and consider its distinct conjugates...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The map $\tau: \zeta \rightarrow \zeta^3$ is a generator of the automorphism group of $Q(\zeta)$, $\zeta^7=1$, $\zeta\ne 1$. Your automorphism $\sigma: \zeta \rightarrow \zeta^2$ is $\tau^2$, so it represents an element of order 3 in the Galois group.  So its fixed field is a quadratic extension of $K$ of  $Q$.

The coefficients of your cubic polynomial  $f$ lie in $K$ not in $Q$.  You have computed the minimal polynomial over $K$ instead of $Q$. The field $K$ has one non-trivial automorphism induced by complex conjugation so to obtain the irreducible polynomial over $Q$ we just compute $g=f\bar{f}$ (applying complex conjugation to the coefficients). 
Complex conjugation is also an automorphism of the field $Q(\zeta)$ also and it is given by $\zeta\rightarrow \zeta^{-1}=\zeta^6$ (it is $\tau^3$). Complex conjugation does not belong to the subgroup generated by your element $\sigma$.

Your cubic is $f=x^3+x^2+\frac{3+\sqrt{-7}}{2}x-1$, $\bar{f}=x^3+x^2+\frac{3-\sqrt{-7}}{2}x-1$ and $g=f\bar{f}=x^6+2x^5+4x^4+x^3+2x^2-3x+1$.

This is the exactly the same as multiplying all $\prod_{i=0}^5 (x-\tau^i(\zeta+\zeta^5))$, since $f=\prod_{i=0}^2 (x-\tau^{2i}(\zeta+\zeta^5))$ and $\bar{f}=\prod_{i=0}^2 (x-\tau^{2i+1}(\zeta+\zeta^5))$

Comment: This is simple and perfect... How do i make sure this is irreducible?? Reduction can not be into a polynomial of degree $3$ and $3$ and it can not be $5,1$ so it has to be $2,4$ and then should i take $(x-a)(x-b)$ for all $a,b$ in those conjugates and prove this is not a polynomial in $\mathbb{Q}[x]$...

Comment: I am tempted to accept this answer but irreducibility is what stopping me... I need to convince my self that this is irreducible.. Thank you so much :)

Comment: @PraphullaKoushik You can easily check that for $u=s+s^5$ then 1, u, u^2, u^3 are linearly independent over the rationals (using that $1, s, s^2, s^3, s^4, s^5, s^6$ are linearly independent over $Q$). Thus $u$ can't satisfy a rational polynomial of degree at most 3.  It then follows easily that the degree 6 polynomial is irreducible.

Comment: @PraphullaKoushik I should have said $1, s, \cdots, s^5$ are independent.

Comment: And a simpler way of seeing the irreducibility is to observe that $\zeta^5+\zeta$ has six **distinct** conjugates. As they must also be zeros of $m(x)$, we must have $\deg m(x)=6$.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen That is not correct. For example the conjugates of $\sqrt{2}$ over the rationals are distinct but not linearly independent.

Comment: I was just pointing out that the degree of the minimal polynomial is equal to the number of distinct conjugates. Their eventual linear dependence is irrelevant. Also $\sqrt2$ has two distinct conjugates over $\Bbb{Q}$, so its minimal polynomial is quadratic (in accordance with my comment) - quite independently from the fact that its conjugates happen to be linearly dependent.

Comment: I got it.. Thank you :)

Answer (score 4):

Because $7$ is prime, we know that, $Aut(\mathbb{Q}[\zeta_7]/\mathbb{Q}) \cong \mathbb{Z}_7^\times \cong \mathbb{Z}_6$.

From here, we wish to find a generator for that automorphism group.  Note that $\mathbb{Q}[\zeta_7]$ is the splitting field for the irreducible polynomial $f(x) = x^6 + x^5 + \cdots + x + 1$ whose roots are the $6$ nontrivial $7$th roots of unity.  Now, it is a theorem that the automorphism group acts transitively on the roots of the polynomial $\iff$ that polynomial is irreducible.  Therefore, we know there must exist an automorphism within this group such that $\zeta \mapsto \zeta^n$ for any $n \in \{1, 2, ..., 5\}$.  The easiest way I know how to do this is through experimentation.

Once you've found your generator, $\phi$, then your automorphism group is simply $\{id, \phi, \phi^2, ..., \phi^5\}$.

The motivation behind all this work was that you need to let your *entire* automorphism group act on $\zeta + \zeta_5$ to generate the minimal polynomial.  If we denote $\{\alpha_1, \alpha_2, ..., \alpha_k \}$ as the orbit of $\zeta + \zeta^5$ under this action, then the minimal polynomial will be be $m(x) = \displaystyle \prod_{i=1}^k\Big(x-\alpha_i\Big)$.

**The moral of the story is that you had the right idea, but the previous sentence is where you went astray.**

---

**Edit**: It is not necessary to actually find the generator, but it *is* necessary to let the entire automorphism group act on $\zeta + \zeta^5$.  Note that there will be an automorphism that maps $\zeta \mapsto \zeta^k$ for all $k$ by the reasoning above, and each one must (obviously) be unique.  Thus, the $6$ of them are:

- $\zeta \mapsto \zeta$
- $\zeta \mapsto \zeta^2$
- $\zeta \mapsto \zeta^3$

etc.

To conclude, if possible, I would recommend you find a copy of Artin and read Chapter 14, Section 4, Proposition 4.4.  I think that would get to the crux of where you went wrong initially.  You can find a .pdf version of this text here:  http://www.drchristiansalas.org.uk/MathsandPhysics/AbstractAlgebra/ArtinAlgebra.pdf

Comment: Oh.. I was thinking i can take any $σ$ and consider its distinct conjugates..

Comment: I have got a problem... I could see that $\sigma(\zeta)=\zeta^5$ generates the galois group but the computation is becoming so messy...Could you suggest some way to make it simple..

Comment: @PraphullaKoushik, indeed.  You can mod the exponent out by $7$ each time.  That is, $\zeta \mapsto \zeta^5 \mapsto \zeta^{25}$.  And at this point, recognize that $\zeta^{25} = \zeta^{4}$.  You can continue in that fashion each time you iterate the automorphism.  So the next one will be $\zeta^4 \mapsto \zeta^{20} = \zeta^6$.

Comment: yes.. i know that and I did that.... there are so many terms.. This would be definitely good for roots of unity which are not prime but in this case it is becoming messy... If there is no other way i would do in this way only..

Comment: @PraphullaKoushik, if you are referring to actually finding which automorphism generates the Galois group, then you're not going to do much better than trial and error and some drudgery.  The problem is equivalent to finding primitive roots modulo a prime, which is discussed here: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/84148/efficiently-find-the-generators-of-a-cyclic-group

Comment: No.. I was not referring to finding which automorphism generates the galois group... After finding generator i have to consider $(x-\alpha)(x-\sigma(\alpha))\cdots (x-\sigma^{n-1}(\alpha))$.. I am saying simplifying this is becoming difficult....

Comment: @Praphulla you don't really need to find a generator of the Galois group. The automorphisms are of the form $\zeta\mapsto \zeta^k$, $k=1,2,\ldots,6$, and this time you need all of them. Thus
$$m(x)=\prod_{i=1}^6(x-\zeta^i-\zeta^{5i}).$$ Simplifying this is not my idea of fun either.

Comment: $\zeta\to\zeta^3$ has order 6, no?

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen : I am aware of generator for galois groups.. Simplifying is what troubles me... Could you suggest something which makes this less complicated..

Comment: @GerryMyerson : Yes Yes... I know that... I mean i have problem in simplification and not conceptual.... Could you please  suggest something which could be less laborious...

Comment: I wasn't talking to you, Praphulla, I was talking to Kaj, who wrote that it has order 3. But as for your question, there are some things that just inherently take a lot of calculation. You can maybe simplify things a little bit by pairing up the terms so first you multiply $(x-\zeta^i-\zeta^{5i})(x-\zeta^{-i}-\zeta^{-5i})$, also you can maybe make use along the way of $$1+\zeta+\cdots+\zeta^6=0$$ but I don't see why there should be any simple way to do these things.

Comment: @Praphulla: All I can say right away is that doing the calculation in the finite field $\Bbb{F}_8$ tells me that
$$m(x)\equiv (x^3+x^2+1)(x+1)^3\equiv x^6+x^3+x+1\pmod2.$$Simplification of your polynomial is, of course, no problem at all for Mathematica. Also sprach Wolfram:
$$m(x)=x^6+2x^5+4x^4+x^3+2x^2-3x+1$$ confirming my characteristic two calculation. But this is not very useful in an exam :-/

Comment: Multiply your cubic by its complex conjugate. Your cubic is $x^3+x^2+ \frac{1}{2}(3+\sqrt{7}I)x-1$

Comment: @i.m.soloveichik : I am sorry, I did not get your point....

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen : I did not understand how did you do your calculation in finite field $F_8$.. Please make it as an answer.. i feel bad to disturb this answer...

Comment: @Praphulla Your polynomial is irreducible over $Q(\sqrt{-7})$ so multiply by its complex conjugate to get an irreducible polynomial over $Q$

Comment: @i.m.soloveichik : I am sorry, I am not getting your point... please make it as a separate answer...

Comment: @i.m.soloveichik : please make your comment as an answer...

Comment: @PraphullaKoushik: I think that the suggestion by i.m.soloveichik is the best idea we've seen here. By happenstance I have written an [earlier answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/299417/11619), where the key relation (due to Gauss himself!) between powers of $\zeta$ and $\sqrt{-7}$ is explained.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen : Yes... I realized that just now.... :)

Comment: Wow!  I leave for a few hours and come back to a small novel underneath my post.  Let me address some comments, and I'll make some edits.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen, of course!  I should've noticed that.  It certainly is not necessary to find a generator, and I'll edit my post accordingly.

Comment: @GerryMyerson, You are correct!  That's what I get for trying to do algebra in the wee hours of the morning.  $\zeta \mapsto \zeta^3$ has order $6$.

Comment: @PraphullaKoushik, I made some edits to the original post.  In particular, read the paragraph about constructing the minimal polynomial since my original response was inaccurate.

Comment: @KajHansen : Yes.. That is helpful.. Thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

Credits for this answer are for Jyrki Lahtonen and i.m.soloveichik

I have considered Only $(x-(\zeta+\zeta^5))(x-(\zeta^2+\zeta^3))(x-(\zeta^4+\zeta^6))$ and simplified this to $$x^3+x^2+(2+\zeta+\zeta^2+\zeta^4)x-1$$

Now i would consider other conjugates of $\zeta+\zeta^5$ namely $\zeta^6+\zeta^2;\zeta^5+\zeta^4;\zeta^3+\zeta$

With Jyrki Lahtonen's link [Is $\sqrt 7$ the sum of roots of unity?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/299409/is-sqrt-7-the-sum-of-roots-of-unity/299417#299417) we see that for $S=\zeta+\zeta^2+\zeta^4$ we have 
$$(2S+1)^2=-7\Rightarrow S=\dfrac{i\sqrt{7}-1}{2}\Rightarrow 2+\zeta+\zeta^2+\zeta^4=2+S=\dfrac{i\sqrt{7}+3}{2}$$

So, My polynomial is $$f(x)=(x^3+x^2+(\dfrac{i\sqrt{7}+3}{2})x+1)$$

As i was missing conjugates I would consider conjugate of the polynomial $f(x)$ and multiply with $f(x)$

Conjugate of $f(x)$ is

$$f(x)=(x^3+x^2+(\dfrac{-i\sqrt{7}+3}{2})x+1)$$

Now i multiply (I did with pen and paper and do not want to write those calculations here) and realized that their product is

$$g(x)=x^6+2x^5+4x^4+x^3+2x^2-3x+1$$

Comment: You’ve got a couple of typos in your expression for the $X^2$-term of $g$. I got $g(X)=1 - 3X + 2X^2 + X^3 + 4X^4 + 2X^5 + X^6$

Comment: @Lubin: Edited.. Thank you :)