explicit isomorphism from $(\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z})^{\times}$ to $Z_{p-1}$
It is well known that the finite subgroups of the multiplicative subgroup $F^{\times}$ of a field $F$ is cyclic.
For the field $\mathbb{F}_p$, its multiplicative subgroup $(\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z})^{\times}$ is cyclic of order $\varphi(p)={p-1}$, so it is isomorphic to $Z_{p-1}$ the cyclic group of order $p-1$. But is there an explicit isomorphism between $(\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z})^{\times}$ and $Z_{p-1}$? I can not find a generator of $(\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z})^{\times}$.

A similar question is asked here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/84148/efficiently-find-the-generators-of-a-cyclic-group/

Good job finding that older version @testaccount! I think the answer and the comments there tell everything known about this problem.

Yes, this link helps me a lot, thanks @testaccount

As you say $(\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z})^{\times}$ is known to be cyclic of order $p-1$.
However, in general we do not know a simple formula or an expression for a generator of $(\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z})^{\times}$. Even finding a fast algorithm for finding a primitive root modulo $p$ seems to be an open problem.
See for example the wikipedia page https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primitive_root_modulo_n and references there.
